# Is there any optimal PHP.ini settings to make the script (meant for data processing) run consistently for longer hours (usually upto 16)?

Tags: php, ini, data-processing

I have a Script which processes for every incoming record coming through REST API calls and after processing, it returns the processed data back through the same manner. It perform well for shorter periods but when it comes to longer periods as mentioned, the script stops running for a brief amount of time before processing again. My current PHP.INI settings are :

```
max_execution_time : 0
max_input_time : -1
max_input_vars : 10000000
memory_limit : -1
post_max_size : 30M
session.gc_maxlifetime : 2592000
upload_max_filesize : 30M
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have a script that runs for 16 hours?

Comment: Yeah, have one or two use cases for the longer duration.